# Session cookie params when using database to store sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am struggling to find info on PHP's session_set_cookie_params() affect on sessions that are being stored in a database. Have searched SO and google and referred to the manual, but no luck.

1) Is this function still used in exactly the same way as when using the default file storage for sessions?

2) A more generic session question then (file based approach) - when a session expires, is it deleted from the file system, or does that take place with the auto 'garbage collection', the probability of which is set in php.ini?

3) How is the first parameter (session lifetime) handled when using a database to store the session data? Because without a custom function/method, deletion from the database is not possible. Or does the session expire in the same way as file approach, but the garbage collection needs to be handled with a custom function?

I'm using the following article as a go-to at the moment;

[How to save PHP sessions to a database](http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1) This function configures the cookie that php sends to the client so it works as expected. <strike>The `session_set_cookie_params()` function only applies if you use the default PHP session implementation which stores session data on the disk in the folder defined by `session.save_path`</strike>

2) When using php's session implementation garbage collection happens automatically based on the `session.gb_*` ini settings. Each time a session is started there is a probability that the garbage collector is ran which will clean up all data from expired sessions.

3) You'll need to implement your own garbage collection routines if you use database storage for your sessions. You can use the probability ini settings to determine when to run garbage collection (see gb_probability and gb_divisor). Garbage collection is performed right after starting the session in most cases. That's when you should see if it should run, and if it runs query your database and remove all stale records. This assumes you also store expiration data with your records so you can actually evaluate if the record is stale or not.

---

That being said, don't reinvent the wheel and use one of the many Session libraries that already implement custom save handlers.

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.save-handler.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

Comment: Are you sure about 1)? I don’t see why PHP should behave differently in that regard, just because a custom session handler is used – the session id still needs to get passed between client and server.

Comment: I'm really surprised at that too, especially since the manual doesn't mention this. Regarding point 2 - so essentially a session expiring doesn't mean it's deleted, this happens with garbage collection?

Comment: @CBroe you are right, i've jumped the horse a little too fast here ... the function in question configures the cookie that's being stored on the client side, nothing to do with the actual storage of the session.

Comment: @CIvemy: Sessions do not “actively” expire – as long as the session data is still stored on the server, it can be accessed as long as the client sends the correct session id. Session data is only deleted by the garbage collector (that then has to check the last access time of the session.)

Comment: Thanks guys. How do you mean they don't expire? Do they not expire, but not delete? So setting the first parameter (lifetime) will expire (and therefore invalidate) the session as with the default file approach, but the garbage collection method (custom) will delete from database?